# Stretch div to bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to stretch the sidebar of my page to the bottom. I've done research and applied all the code that I needed to (html/body set to width: 100%, etc etc) and it's still not working. I suspect something is overriding my height properties; I'm just not sure what.

My code is a bit complicated to show here so please use the "Inspect Element Tool" to view the code:

http://tarawilder.com/staging/

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Yes the one on the left. To Mayank: I'll work on that now! Thanks!

Comment: deleted my last comment......and going through the source code....if you check your markup...there is something wrong...`</html></div></div>` at the end of page (check your markups first!!)  :)!!!!!!

Comment: When I look at my footer, I don't see those closing div tags! I'll have to go through and see what I may have left open accidentally. Thank you for pointing that out! Edit: Found them!

Answer (score 2):

Add `position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0;` to you `.sidebar` class, and `margin-left:16.666666666666664%` to your `.col-md-10` class.

Comment: That's so simple.  I never realized you could use both top and bottom at the same time.  Does that work reliably cross-browser?

Comment: @Buh Buh it seems so. I have created a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EDsey) to demonstrate, which works for Chrome, IE9+, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text\javascript">
   window.onload = function(){document.getElementById('test').style.height = (screen.availHeight) + 'px';
}
</script>
```

place this script in a head tag.
What it does is, when the page is loaded it gets the value of the available height and sets it to your div

Comment: It didn't work :S Also, I'd rather not use Javascript. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something with background image on the `<body>`, which repeats vertically downwards.

The div itself would not really stretch to the bottom, but it would look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solutions but here is what I've decided on doing:

Make the container have overflow:hidden, then have the sidebar have padding: 5000px and margin: -5000px

Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds like a really nasty hack. Try looking at the code on this page: http://www.css-lab.com/demos/stickfoot/min-ht-fixfoot.html That's what I usually use when I'm trying to do a similar thing, as I can never get it right either.

And if you're just working with that sidebar, this example might be of use as well: http://www.css-lab.com/demos/3col/3col-full-sdbr.html

(Just view the source code on these links. The guy keeps it really easy under the hood so you can learn just by looking at the source.)